# remove a attribute recursively in a object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is simple data, i want to recursively remove the children attribute if the children attribute represents a empty array.

```
[{"name":"code","created":"2022-03-27T05:42:28.977Z","children":[],"path":"623ff9881a6e94547deaebed"}]
```

my code is as shown

```
  function removeMeta(obj) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for(let key in keys) {
      console.log('.......',key,obj[key]);
      if(typeof(obj[key]) == 'object'){
        removeMeta(obj[key]);
      }else if( key == 'children' && obj[key] ==[]){
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  }
```

but it doesn't seem to work, any idea

Comment: The `typeof`  the children property will be 'object', so you'll never perform the `delete`.

Comment: do you have only in `children` children? do you have other properties with nested objects or arrays? please add a complete example data set.

Answer (score 0):

These are the issues:

- The `typeof` the children property will be 'object', so your code will never perform the `delete`.

  Remove the `else` from `else if`, so that that `if` is always executed.
- `obj[key] ==[]` will always be false, as it compares with a newly created array -- by reference. Instead check the length:

  ```
  obj[key].length == 0
  ```
- The `for` loop should be a `for..of` loop, not a `for..in` loop

Corrected:

```js
function removeMeta(obj) {
  let keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for(let key of keys) {
    if(typeof(obj[key]) == 'object'){
      removeMeta(obj[key]);
    }
    if( key == 'children' && obj[key].length == 0){
      delete obj[key];
    }
  }
}

let arr = [{"name":"code","created":"2022-03-27T05:42:28.977Z","children":[],"path":"623ff9881a6e94547deaebed"}];
removeMeta(arr);
console.log(arr);
```